# Slow IIS performance after upgrade from 7.0 to 8.5

Tags: iis, iis-8.5, asp-classic

A website was running on an IIS server 7.0 / Windows 2008. A new server was set up, running IIS 8.5 / Windows 2012, with more powerful hardware (4 CPU cores). However, performance of a new server is dramatically low.
Application is ASP classic. What I noticed is that VBScript-intensive code **totally** blocks other requests! For example, I have a page that loops for ~100000 records. It takes about 20 seconds to do that. During that period other requests, even for static resources, are waiting.
Unfortunately, server is being managed by someone else and I have no access to logs or performance monitors.
What could be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be your problem.  I've experienced the same thing with Server 2008r2 running Classic ASP.  The problem is that the security updates to the server also install internet explorer 9 which overwrites a .dll that controls VBScript.

[https://forums.iis.net/t/1177876.aspx?Classic+Application+Pool+Hang+Problem+with+Classic+ASP+](https://forums.iis.net/t/1177876.aspx?Classic%20Application%20Pool%20Hang%20Problem%20with%20Classic%20ASP%20)